# Intercept activiti database operations

Tags: database, encryption, activiti

I'm working with Activiti 5.14, and I have a requirement:

> All the data in the database should be encrypted.

So, was trying to come up with a solution encrypting the data before to pass to the activiti library, but now I need to lookup for another approach.

I was thinking about *to intercept* of the *save* database operations and save all the data already encrypted and read it decrypted. (I don't mind the performance at this point)

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply use an encrypted at rest database?
Oracle, sqlserver and db2 all offer this capability.